# Using regex to find all lines matching a pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, file

I have:

```
# runPath is the current path, commands is a list that's mostly irrelevant here
def ParseShellScripts(runPath, commands):
    for i in range(len(commands)):
        if commands[i].startswith('{shell}'):
            # todo: add validation/logging for directory `sh` and that scripts actually exist
            with open(os.path.join(runPath, 'sh', commands[i][7:]),"r") as shellFile:
                for matches in re.findall("/^source.*.sh", shellFile):
                    print matches
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "veri.py", line 396, in <module>
    main()
  File "veri.py", line 351, in main
    servList, labels, commands, expectedResponse = ParseConfig(relativeRunPath)
  File "veri.py", line 279, in ParseConfig
    commands = ParseShellScripts(runPath, commands)
  File "veri.py", line 288, in ParseShellScripts
    for matches in re.findall("/^source.*.sh", shellFile):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

**Edit:** *adding some files as examples*

```
#config.sh
#!/bin/bash

dbUser = 'user'
dbPass = 'pass'
dbSchema = ''
dbMaxCons = '4000'

#the shellFile I'm looking in
#!/bin/bash
source config.sh

OUTPUT=$(su - mysql -c "mysqladmin variables" | grep max_connections | awk '{print $4}')
if [[ ${OUTPUT} -ge ${dbMaxCons}]]; then
    echo "Success"
    echo ${OUTPUT}
else
    echo ${OUTPUT}
fi
```

Basically what I want to accomplish is to search through all specefied files in the `sh` directory, and if any of them contain `source*.sh` (e.g., `source config.sh`), print that file (eventually I will be expanding it out and appending it to the top of the current file so that I can pass the single command-string via ssh.. but that's not relevant here I don't think.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shellfile is a file, you want to pass a string. you'll probably have to enumerate the lines first. typically `for matches in re.findall("/^source.*.sh", line) for line in shellfile:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run a `regex.findall` on the file handle `shellFile`. You need to read from that file, and run the regex on the data you read.

Maybe, something like this?

```
with open(os.path.join(runPath, 'sh', commands[i][7:]),"r") as shellFile:
    data = shellFile.read()
    for matches in re.findall("/^source.*.sh", data):
        print matches
```

Comment: It is same solutin i write, but take 1 string of code more. Also it use more memory.

Comment: It's not always about number of lines, especially when the change is trivial. You could write a lot of Python code in one line, and it'd be undecipherable to a reader. The point was to illustrate the OP's mistake. Also, I'm not sure I understand how calling a read in one line takes more memory than calling it in the next.

Comment: 1) Ofc, but if you limit your line to 80-100 chars it's not a problem, 2) You assign data to variable, and memory cleanup will raise only after your "with" close, and with my variant memory cleanup will raise after findall method — before cycle.

Comment: _Premature optimization is the root of all evil_ - Donald E. Knuth

Comment: It is not premature. If you know that is used in just 1 place — why not? :-)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call .read() method

```
for matches in re.findall("/^source.*.sh", shellFile.read())
```